# Windows 8 - USB 3.0 is in poor write speed

Tags: windows-8, usb-3

My notebook is Asus U46E has one USB3 port. I tested the write speed of USB3 in Ubuntu, it's fast as my expectation without doing anything. But when I go to Win8, the data was written in not-right-speed of USB3. I had tried to install drivers from Asus. It's still the same.

EDIT: In the benchmark, I see the read speed is good. Write speed did not pass 15MB/s.

[image: p1]
[image: Drivers]
[image: p3]
[image: p4]
[image: bmark]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try the latest driver version 3.5.97.0 from here:

http://www.station-drivers.com/page/fresco_logic.htm

And I also have this USB controller and I can say that this one is a 1st generation controller which has some issues (that's why MS doesn't use the new USB 3.0 drivers from Windows 8 for this USB controller).

Maybe the Linux drivers have fixed the issues and that's why you see the good speed.

Comment: I have installed the latest one from Fresco. But I still got the same issue. I hope they can fix this soon.

Comment: look if you have activated the Write Cache in the device manager for your USB 3.0 device.